# Prove or disprove: If $[a], [b] \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ are zero divisors, then their product $[a][b]$ is also a zero divisor or it is zero

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

I have attempted to prove that this statement is true. Does my logic check out?

Let $[a], [b]$ be zero divisors. Then $ax \equiv 0\pmod n$ and $by \equiv 0\pmod n$ for some $x ,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. That is to say that $ax = cn$ and $by = dn$ for some $c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $(ax)(by) = cdn^2$, and $(ax)(by) = (a)(b)(xy) = [a][b][xy] = [0]$. Therefore, $[a][b]$ is a zero divisor as well.

Feel free to also criticize the structure of my proof in addition to any logical mistakes. I'm trying to get better with that as well.

Comment: This looks all correct to me. The only thing I'd change is $(a)(b)(xy) \in [a][b][xy]$ instead of $(a)(b)(xy) = [a][b][xy]$ to be more precise.

Comment: Ah yes, I was wondering about this. Thank you for clearing that up! This makes much more sense. I do wonder though - would it make sense to say $(a)(b)(xy) \equiv [a][b][xy]$?

Comment: I don't see why not. Anything to denote that you're working with the equivalence classes modulo $n$ rather than integers would be good.

Comment: Your proof is good but we can and should get out of the habit of translating from modular classes to integers and back.  We *can* say $a,b\in \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ are are zero divisors so there exists an $x,y \in \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ so that $ax\equiv 0\pmod n$ and $by\equiv 0 \pmod n$  so $ab\cdot xy\equiv 0 \pmod n$ and so $xy$ is a zero divisor or $0$.

Comment: BTW if $x$ is a zero divisor every multiple of $x$ is a zero divisor (or zero) as well.  No need to take the product of *two* zero divisors.  The product of *one* zero divisor and *anything* is good enough.  (I trust you will be easily able to see the proof-- it's exactly the same but easier.)

Comment: I appreciate that feedback. I didn't like the clunkiness of going from modular classes to integers and back. I much prefer the way you just showed it. And yes, that proof does seem very similar. I did it the way I did due to how the question was asked. Would showing any multiple of a zero divisior is also a zero divisor be considered cleaner?